# binding to controller object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm new to angular, trying to bind an an element's content into the controller's Scope to be able to use it within another function:

here is the scenario am working around:

I want the content of the `<span>` element  `{{y.facetName}}` in

```
<span ng-model="columnFacetname">{{y.facetName}}</span>
```

to be sent to the controller an be put in the object `$scope.columnFacetname` in the controller

Here is a snippet of what I'm working on:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in x.facetArr|limitTo: limit track by $index ">
        <div class="list_items panel-body ">
            <button class="ButtonforAccordion" ng-click="ListClicktnColumnFilterfunc(); onServerSideButtonItemsRequested(ListClicktnColumnFilter, myOrderBy)">
                <span>{{$index+1}}</span>
                <span ng-model="columnFacetname">{{y.facetName}}</span>
                <span>{{y.facetValue}}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
</div>

angular.module('mainModule').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.columnFacetname = "";
                $scope.ListClicktnColumnFilter = "";
                $scope.ListClicktnColumnFilterfunc = function() {
                    $scope.ListClicktnColumnFilter = "\":\'" + $scope.columnFacetname + "\'";
                };
            }
```

the problem is that the  `$scope.ListClicktnColumnFilter` doesn't show the `$scope.columnFacetname` within it, meaning that the `$scope.columnFacetname`  is not well-binded.

Comment: you are looping via ng-repeat so how to you expect to map multiple/different `y.facetName` values to map to single `columnFacetname` variable?

Comment: Did you try to just remove the "ng-model" ?

Comment: yes i did, but nothing changed;

Comment: @kachhalimbu  I am mapping the item that is clicked, and it works.
when the element is clicked the value will be added to the scope's object.. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ng-click instead of calling two different function

```
ng-click="ListClicktnColumnFilterfunc(); onServerSideButtonItemsRequested(ListClicktnColumnFilter, myOrderBy)"
```

you can declare like this

```
ng-click="columnFacetname = y.facetName; onServerSideButtonItemsRequested(columnFacetname , myOrderBy)"
```

You are trying to pass that model to another function by assigning it to `ListClicktnColumnFilter` in your controller

By doing in this way, you can achieve the same thing.

I have done one plunker with sample array,

http://embed.plnkr.co/YIwRLWXEOeK8NmYmT6VK/preview

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is correct @Alhuck A , I used that way and it worked.. 
Here is how i used it 

ng-click="ListClicktnColumnFilterfunc(x.facetOuterName,y.facetName)"

Thank you